# Alamofire progress.fractionCompleted is null

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I download image from server with Alamofire framework. I need progress downloading but i can't get it.

```
Alamofire.download(requestForImage, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil, to: self.destination)
        .downloadProgress{ progress in
        self.progressView.progress = progress.fractionCompleted
            print(progress.fractionCompleted)
        }

        .response{ response in

            if let headers = response.response?.allHeaderFields as? [String: String]{
                print("headers = \(headers)")
                // ...
            }


            if response.error == nil, let imagePath = response.destinationURL?.path {
                self.progressView.progress = 1
                let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath)
                print("Image is successfully downloaded!")
                self.addNewImageToTheScrollView(img: image)
            }
        }
}
```

progress.fractionCompleted = 0.0 , progress.totalUnitCount = -1
I found one hint on alamofire github - to set for server response 
header("Content-length: ".$size); 
but it doesn't help, Have anybody any idea?) All other with this framework works as should

Answer (score 1):

For many people it works to make sure the webserver delivers the correct `Content-Length`, see https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1467

If this didn't helps, you can do a little work-a-round, by getting the head first, reading the `Content-Length` and then calculating the progress by yourself.

```
Alamofire.request( url, method: .head )
  .validate()
  .response { response in

    if let error = response.error {
      print( "ERROR: Can't get head for \(url) \(error)" )
    } else {
      if let response = response.response {
        if let contentLengthHeader = response.allHeaderFields["Content-Length"], 
           let contentLengthInt = Int( "\(contentLengthHeader)" ) 
        {
          Alamofire.download( url,
            method: .get, parameters: nil,
            encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil, to: destination 
          )
            .downloadProgress{ progress in
              print( progress.fractionCompleted )
              print( Float( progress.completedUnitCount ) / Float( contentLengthInt ) )
            }
            .validate()
            .response{ response in
              if let error = response.error {
                print( "ERROR: Can't get image for \(url) \(error)" )
              } else {
                if let imagePath = response.destinationURL?.path {
                  let image = UIImage( contentsOfFile: imagePath )
                }
              }
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

If you use Alamofires `responseJSON` and have a compressed file, like `.json.gz` you have to know the size of the uncompressed file to calculate the progress, because `progress.completedUnitCount` gives you the completed bytes of the uncompressed file.

You can add this size to the header on the server side with `Content-Length-Decompressed`. Than you just have to use `Content-Length-Decompressed` instead of `Content-Length` in the code above.